# Getting warning when app published to google platstore - Cleartext traffic allowed for all domains and Your app accepts user certificates - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play, warnings, publish

[image]

Your app accepts user certificates when verifying secure connections.
Your app's Network Security Configuration allows the use of user-specified certificates. This could allow eavesdroppers to intercept data sent by your app, or to modify data in transit.

Consider nesting the trust-anchors element that allows user certificates inside a debug-overrides element to make sure they are only available when android:debuggable is set to true.

Cleartext traffic allowed for all domains
Your app's Network Security Configuration allows cleartext traffic for all domains. This could allow eavesdroppers to intercept data sent by your app. If that data is sensitive or user-identifiable it could impact the privacy of your users.

Consider only permitting encrypted traffic by setting the cleartextTrafficPermitted flag to false, or adding an encrypted policy for specific domains.

Stuck with this issue and not able to find solution for flutter

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have used `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest` file.

In simple terms what it does is allows `HTTP` traffic to your app. `HTTP` is considered as not secure to threats. You can either set is to false `android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"` in `AndroidManifest` file or ignore the warnings.

You should set it to `true` only if your connection to API can not establish through `HTTPS`.

Comment: the second warning from the screenshot is also for the same reason?

Comment: It seems like both are related to each other.